# Paypal says my CancelURL is invalid?

Tags: paypal

I'm creating a site and am just adding in payments.
I'm using the [Paypal SDK](https://github.com/paypalx/SDKs/tree/master/Merchant/merchant-php-sdk) and have setup my `SetExpressCheckout()`.

Here is the response,

```
object(SetExpressCheckoutResponseType)[72]
  public 'Token' => null
  public 'Timestamp' => string '2012-08-23T15:21:15Z' (length=20)
  public 'Ack' => string 'Failure' (length=7)
  public 'CorrelationID' => string 'e0278e8e18b4f' (length=13)
  public 'Errors' => 
    object(ErrorType)[78]
      public 'ShortMessage' => string 'Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details.' (length=94)
      public 'LongMessage' => string 'CancelURL is invalid.' (length=21)
      public 'ErrorCode' => string '10472' (length=5)
      public 'SeverityCode' => string 'Error' (length=5)
      public 'ErrorParameters' => null
  public 'Version' => string '93.0' (length=4)
  public 'Build' => string '3556406' (length=7)
```

I'm not sure what's up. My `CancelURL` looks like, `urlencode('https://www.example.com/users/account/');`. I've included the trailing slash, which some people think can cause it to be invalid.

The only thing that I can think of is that because my site isn't online anywhere, that Paypal can't reach the page. I have created a dummy page and uploaded it into `/users/account/` on the server so it's reachable and still nothing. I also have an entry in my `etc/hosts` to route `example.com` traffic to my localhost which worked fine for my Facebook Auth bits.

Anyone have any ideas on what the restrictions are for a CancelURL and why Paypal is kicking my request?

---

**Request generation**

```
$int = new PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService();

$amount = new BasicAmountType();
$amount->currencyID = CakeSession::read('Locale.currency');
$amount->value = Configure::read('Subscription.price.'.CakeSession::read('Locale.shortname'));

$req_details_type = new SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType();

$req_details_type->OrderTotal = $amount;
$req_details_type->ReturnURL = urlencode('https://www.example.com/paypal/getExpressCheckoutDetails');
$req_details_type->CancelURL = urlencode('https://www.example.com/users/account/');
$req_details_type->MaxAmount = $amount;
$req_details_type->OrderDescription = "Monthly subscription to Example.com Pro";
$req_details_type->ReqConfirmShipping = 0;
$req_details_type->NoShipping = 1;
$req_details_type->LocaleCode = CakeSession::read('Locale.shortname') == 'usa'? 'US' : 'GB';
$req_details_type->PaymentAction = 'Authorization';
$req_details_type->BuyerEmail = AuthComponent::user('email');
$req_details_type->BrandName = urlencode("Example.com");

$req_type = new SetExpressCheckoutRequestType();
$req_type->SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails = $req_details_type;

$req = new SetExpressCheckoutReq();
$req->SetExpressCheckoutRequest = $req_type;


$response = $int->SetExpressCheckout($req);

var_dump($response);
```

Comment: Can you include a copy of the actual SetExpressCheckout API request (minus your credentials)?

Comment: I meant the actual SetExpressCheckout API request; so the output from var_dump($request). :-)

Comment: @Robert That's it. As I mentioned I'm using the Paypal SDK, so the request is comprised of an instansiation of three classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must change :

```
$req_details_type->ReturnURL = urlencode('https://www.example.com/paypal/getExpressCheckoutDetails');
$req_details_type->CancelURL = urlencode('https://www.example.com/users/account/');
```

by :

```
$req_details_type->ReturnURL = 'https://www.example.com/paypal/getExpressCheckoutDetails';
$req_details_type->CancelURL = 'https://www.example.com/users/account/';
```

urlencode(); is not needed here it convert you'r url into a string